# Callback of MQTT.js subscribe() function not capturing error message

Tags: javascript, mqtt

I am using MQTT.js to subscribe to real time telemetry data.

```
client.on('connect', function () {  
    console.log('client connected');
    client.subscribe('flespi/state/gw/devices/' + flespi_id + '/telemetry/position', 
      { qos: 0 }, 
      function (err, granted){
        console.log(err.toString());
      }
   );      
}
=>client connected
=>Uncaught TypeError: err is null
```

Sometimes subscribe is unsuccessful so I use the callback function as indicated in the [docs](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js/#mqttclientsubscribetopictopic-arraytopic-object-options-callback) to retrieve the error.

I have on purpose given a wrong subscription token so even though it connects, it can't subscribe. The problem is that it says there is no error (`err is null`). So how can I know what the error is?

There is a similar question here, but for `publish()` instead of `subscribe()`: [How to catch "access error" when publish inaccessible topic in mqtt.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58048539/how-to-catch-access-error-when-publish-inaccessible-topic-in-mqtt-js)

Comment: By "wrong subscription token" I assume you mean topic? Subscribing to a unused topic will not cause an error, you will just not get any messages.

Comment: This is the data I use to generate the access token, it has 3 ids for vehicles and the id of the vehicle I am requesting is not there, so it connects but doesn't subscribe. If I add the id then it works. `const data = '[{"access":{"acl":[{"methods":["GET"],"submodules":[{"methods":["GET"],"name":"telemetry"}],"uri":"gw/devices","ids":[874813, 866121, 831573]}],"type":2},"info":"user-acl-dashboard","ttl":600}]';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the [MQTT js docs](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js#subscribe) carefully and read something about the actual MQTT messages too - ideally [the standard itself](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718068) or the [nice interpretation](https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-4-mqtt-publish-subscribe-unsubscribe/) at HiveMQ. The `err` callback parameter is for global failures, like transport layer errors. If the client sends a malformed topic name, or the client has insufficient permissions (this is exactly what HiveMQ mentions), you will find your failure as 0x80 code in the the `granted` array.

If the particular topic does not exist yet on the particular broker, that's not an error in MQTT. You may subscribe to wildcards, how the broker should handle that? Topic may start existing only when a first message is published to it.

Comment: This is my granted array `(1) […]
​
0: Object { topic: "flespi/state/gw/devices/874829/telemetry/position", qos: 0, nl: false, … }
​
length: 1
​
<prototype>: Array []` And it is exactly the same as the granted array I get when there is no error. How do I find that 0x80 code?

Comment: Ah, alright, i should correct myself. See the updated answer, please. Try sending a malformed topic, or configure the broker so that it prohibits the client. You'll see 0x80.