# mqtt.js: catching access error via PUBREC reason codes?

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, mqtt.js

In my setup I have a mqtt.js client which publishes to a mosquitto broker (qos: 2). Now I have the problem that some messages are silently dropped by mosquitto because the client is unauthorized to publish to that specific topic. In [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58048539/how-to-catch-access-error-when-publish-inaccessible-topic-in-mqtt-js) it is said that it is not possible to recognize that as client because that would be a security issue. However it seems that [mosquitto sends a "not-authorized"](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/1654) reason code in the PUBREC message. Wouldn't it be possible for the client to still get the info that it can not publish to that topic? What am I getting wrong?

Comment: I answered the solution in the original question so this question above can be deleted as it is now a dulicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58048539/how-to-catch-access-error-when-publish-inaccessible-topic-in-mqtt-js

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to parse it out of the PUBREC packet yourself by registering an `packetreceive` callback

```
client.on('packetreceive', function(packet){

})
```